# Ansible module failure. "/bin/sh: sudo: command not found" although it is available on machine I am running against

Tags: ansible, sudo

I have a Gitlab pipeline that uses a gitlab runner to deploy from. From the runner, I run ansible to reach out and configure one of our servers.

In my pipeline step where I run ansible-playbook, I have the following setup:

```
deploy:
image: registry.com/ansible
stage: deploy
script:
 - ansible-playbook server.yml --inventory=hosts.yml
```

This reaches out to my host and begins to deploy but hits a snag on the first task that has a "become: yes" statement in it.  It fails providing the following error:

```
TASK [mytask : taskOne] ************
task path: my/file/location/path.yml
fatal: [server01[ : FAILED! => {
  "changed": false,
  "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: sudo: command not found\n",
  "module_stdout": "",
  "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
```

I can login to my server (server01) and run sudo without issues. Any thoughts on what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `sudo` installed? What happens if you run something like `ssh <theremotehost> sudo <somecommand>`?

Comment: @larsks  sudo is installed at /usr/bin/sudo/. It is a part of my path. 
I ran ssh <myhost> sudo ls /etc/ and it returned successfully.

Comment: Please add you ansible task definition to the question. Moreover, a more appropriate manual test (i.e. closer to ansible reality) is `ssh <remotehost> "/bin/sh -c 'sudo <somecommand>'`. If this fails by any chance, you might want to try `ssh <remotehost> "/bin/sh -c 'echo $PATH'`. If `/usr/bin` is not in the output you then have to find out why. Else I'm a bit out of ideas...

Answer (score 2):

**My guess** is that you are not using the same user in the GitLab pipeline and for your `sudo` test on the machine. In this case you should try to become this user on the host and try the `sudo` command to troubleshoot it. It seems to be a matter of `PATH` not something related to the configuration of the sudoers (that is a common problem).

As a **workaround** (it will not solve the `sudo` problem) you could try to use an alternate `become_method` like `su`, more detail in the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html).

```yaml
- name: Run a command with become su
  command: somecommand
  become: yes
  become_method: su
```

Answer (score 0):

Logged in just for this. Romain's answer really helped me with my troubleshooting.

For me, the ansible collection that I was using needed sudo privileges. Due to this I needed to run my playbook with sudo user. As well as have the ansible-galaxy collection downloaded by a sudo user.

I had to use `sudo su` to switch to the user. Then run `ansible-galaxy collection install [COLLECTION NAME] --force`. After that I could run my playbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `become: True` set anywhere above try removing that and just include `become_method: sudo`

I think this should help you